# Ruby interpreter optimization

Tags: ruby, optimization, interpreter

I was looking for information on Ruby's interpreter. I know it's an interpreted language and I wanted information as to whether optimization was done on the fly. A simple example would be the fiz-buzz problem. Does the interpreter convert trying to solve x%3 == 0 && x%5 == 0 to x%15 == 0 ? 
It is easy to see gcc flags and what they do. Is there somewhere I can see the same for ruby?
What does the interpreter do exactly?

Comment: "exactly?" Exactly? You're asking for an answer the size of a book. That's way out of scope for Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 0):

Not really an answer, but a counter-example:

```
class Fixnum
  def %(obj)
    obj < 10 ? 0 : 1
  end
end

x = 15

x % 3 == 0 && x % 5 == 0
# => true

x % 15 == 0
# => false
```

It's hard to optimize this expression without knowing what `x` is or how `x#%` is implemented.

Comment: I was assuming x as being just an integer (as I said, the fiz-buz problem)

Comment: @Max That doesn't change anything. Parser engines typically don't make mathematical optimizations since there is a seemingly infinite amount of them.

Comment: @Max I've updated my answer. In Ruby even `15` is an object that can be changed.

Answer (score 0):

Since it is an interpreted language, it will run through the code one line at a time, until the first error.  There are some optimizations as to how each line is evaluated, but these should also appear in other languages.  e.g. lazy evaluation:

```
false && x>4 && x!=0
```

after the false followed by logical 'and', it just ignores the rest.  You can have the interpreter load certain things on startup in your ~/.irbrc , if you wish.